# i have alreday import matcardmodule but issue not resolved

Tags: angular, angular-material

ERROR in 'mat-card' is not a known element:

1. If 'mat-card' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-card' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("item" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="0 1 33.33" *ngFor="let item of [1,2,3,4,5]">

   ```
                [ERROR ->]<mat-card fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start start">
                    <div class="left_cta">")
   ```

Comment: Did you add `MatCardModule` to your `AppModule`?

Comment: Could you please share your **app.module.ts** file? @Amit Pandey

Comment: Kindly also share your component html